# Ubuntu 18 not getting security updates?

Tags: apt, updates

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1 LTS _bionic Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ bionic main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04.1 LTS _bionic Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe multiverse
```

Update 1:

```
developer@svc:~$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.11
  Candidate: 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.11
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.11 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.29-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Update 2:

```
developer@svc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: What's your basis for assuming you don't get security updates?  Because those repositories specified there *do* give you security updates.

Comment: So, I am in charge of a non-critical staging environment at work. And I swear on this one LAMP server I never see security updates (only upgrades). Its required I do a monthly update/upgrade on it assuming no serious vulnerabilities are known to exist. Other servers seem to always have them.

Comment: What do you mean by 'upgrades'?  Have you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` lately?  What does `apt-cache policy apache2` show?  And are you absolutely certain this one "lamp server" is actually an 18.04 box?

Comment: Yes, I am running the correct command. And yes I am as positive as I can be that it is 18.04. Updated question with additional information. Maybe I am just being paranoid? I checked PHP and it is up to date on the 7.2 (7.2.24) branch according to https://www.php.net/downloads.php though apache website says 2.4 branch latest is 2.4.41 while my local reads 2.4.29...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have setup unattended upgrades so you just dont see it being updated.